# Unable to delete the database file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Using VB.Net

I cannot able to delete the database file. File also not in use.

```
 File.Delete("G:\1.txt") - It is deleting the file

 File.Delete("G:\DB1.bak") - It is not deleting
```

I used below code also,

```
Kill("G:\DB1.bak") - It is also not deleting
```

What is the problem with my code.

Comment: No Error, nothing happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, you said that the file is not in use. Then refer to the following code part to delete all the files from a directory passed to it.

```
Sub DeleteFiles(ByVal Dir As String)
        Dim DirObj As New DirectoryInfo(Dir)

        Dim Files As FileInfo() = DirObj.GetFiles("*.bak")
        Dim Dirs As DirectoryInfo() = DirObj.GetDirectories("*.*")

        Dim Filename As FileInfo

        For Each Filename In Files
            Try
                File.Delete(Filename.FullName)
                Console.WriteLine("Deleted {0}", Filename.FullName)
            Catch E As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Error deleting {0}", Filename.FullName)
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", E.Message)
            End Try
        Next

        Dim DirectoryName As DirectoryInfo

        For Each DirectoryName In Dirs
            Try
                DeleteFiles(DirectoryName.FullName)
            Catch E As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Error accessing {0}", DirectoryName.FullName)
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", E.Message)
            End Try
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is OK to me. May be that file is being used by another process or you (user) don't have permission to delete it.

Comment: @Gopal - Try the instance method -  Delete() of  FileInfo class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your file is actually in use.

To be really sure I would definitely recommend to use Unlocker tool http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ for checking who or what is really using your file, there are chances you are wrong about the usage.